# How can I check the text value when I press on button, rather than whenever text changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I put an input and a button. I want it to go to Home Screen if the password in input is correct when i press on button. But whenever I type in input, it checks the password if its correct,

I am using react native base tho.

How to solve this issue?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Content, Form, Item, Input, Label, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
 
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const CORRECT_PASSWORD = "5555";
  const onEnterPin = (password)=>{
      if(password === CORRECT_PASSWORD) {
      
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("please check your password")
      }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Form>
          <Item stackedLabel last>
            <Label>Enter Password</Label>
            <Input style={{ borderWidth: .1 }} onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
          </Item>
          <Button block onPress={onEnterPin(password)}>
            <Text>Go Home Screen</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>   
  )
}

export default SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is currently called on every re-render. You can change the function call a bit. You also don't need to pass a password as parameter, because it is already defined as state. Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Content, Form, Item, Input, Label, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
 
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const CORRECT_PASSWORD = "5555";
  const onEnterPin = () => {
      if(password === CORRECT_PASSWORD) {
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert("please check your password")
      }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Form>
          <Item stackedLabel last>
            <Label>Enter Password</Label>
            <Input style={{ borderWidth: .1 }} onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
          </Item>
          <Button block onPress={onEnterPin}>
            <Text>Go Home Screen</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>   
  )
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you Sir. Could you tell me why it rerender everytime in previous code? is it becaue i added password as parameter while defining the function?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! When you type onEnterPin(password) in the UI (render) block, the function will called immediately since it's a function call. And every time setPassword is called, then the UI is re-rendered and additionally the function is called again. In the solution, the function is only passed as a parameter and is not called. The button now does the handling.

Comment: You are so good at teaching, thanks I understand now.